# How do I activate Win+Tab keys with a VBScript in an effort to launch Task View in Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vbscript, windows-10, dwm

I am trying to set my mouse's middle button to launch [Task View](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-task-view-in-windows-10/) in Windows 10 (the replacement for [Aero Flip 3D](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/using-aero-flip-3d) in prior Windows versions). I'm using Logitech SetPoint software, which is capable of running an external command when I press the middle mouse button. So my idea to use SendKeys to simuluate hitting the Windows Key + Tab.

Here's my .vbs script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "(^{ESC}{TAB})"
```

However, this doesn't work. It appears to "press" the Windows key followed by the tab key instead of pressing them simultaneously. How can I get them to press at the same time and thus activate Task View? And I don't want to ask an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so is there another way I might go about activating Task View by pressing the middle mouse button in case I'm going about this all wrong?

---

I saw the one alternate way of activating Aero Flip 3D was to run the command `rundll32 DwmApi #105` at the command prompt. But that doesn't seem to activate Task View. Is there another code for Task View?

Comment: My version of setpoint let's me bind keys including modifiers to mouse buttons directly. Does this not work in your version of setpoint or is there some other problem? The reason sendkeys does not work is that it does not support the windows key afaik. ^{ESC} is a shortcut to opening the start menu (which incidently is what also happens when you press the windows key) but it is not the same as a keypress of the windows key.

Comment: @Syberdoor SetPoint doesn't allow you to use the Windows key as a modifier. I did manage to get around that by editing the .xml file where it stores the settings, but unfortunately that means I had to hold the middle mouse button to keep Task View open. My goal is to press it once to activate Task View, and once more to deactivate Task View.

Comment: Ah i understand. I would recommend a small autohotkey or autoit script for that. They should be able to emulate holded key easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Logitech's SetPoint software isn't giving me the option to launch a program anymore. Not sure what's up with that, because I managed to create an AutoIT script to launch Task View.

I updated to the latest version of SetPoint and configured the middle button to activate Document Flip, which apparently maps to Task View in Windows 10 and now it performs how I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.WindowSwitcher
```

Documented under IShellDispatch5

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this could help someone... I found a guide on how to configure Logitech mouse to recognise win key.

Here is the link to that website: [Logitech SetPoint Win Key Mouse Mapping](https://tinkertry.com/logitech-multiple-desktop-mouse-mappings-for-windows-10).

I am tempted to copy that guide over to superuser but not sure whether it is proper/legal to do so.